# Вопрос о нулевом суффиксе

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с нулевым суффиксом, меня интересует его  определение.

С одной стороны,  в Интернете мне встречалась информация о том, что "нулевой суффикс является формообразующим, то есть  имеет грамматическое значение и проявляется на фоне парадигмы (например, рода)". Тогда: вёз(0) – везла, обжёг (0)– обожгла, нулевой суффикс выражает прошедшее время, как и суффикс Л.

C другой стороны,  ходить – ход (1), ожечь – ожог (2).  Здесь, как мне кажется,  нулевой суффикс грамматической формы не выражает и парадигмы не имеет. Значит, это словообразовательный нулевой суффикс? Но какое определение  имеет такой суффикс и различают ли вообще разные виды нулевых суффиксов?

Кроме того,   в первом примере мы усекаем основу глагола, а во втором нет. Можно ли считать, что в обоих случаях используется нулевой суффикс и способ образования слов одинаковый? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Sergey, не заморачивайтесь. Авторы по-разному трактуют понятие нулевого суффикса. Те из них, кто настаивают его на его формообразующей функции, вольно или невольно противопоставляют его *отсутствию* суффикса - в тех случаях, когда эта формообразующая функция не может быть указана. Те же, кто эти случаи не разделяет, и не думают о какой-то особой роли "нулевого суффикса". Поэтому надо четко понимать, с позиции какой школы мы рассматриваем вопрос. В ваших же примерах ("ожог") суффикса просто нет. Он не нулевой. Просто никакого.

О словообразовательном(?) нулевом суффиксе я не слышал. 
А вообще вот посмотрите условия выделения нулевого *словообразующего*  суффикса: 
http://rusolimp.kopeisk.ru/morfemika/?file=111
Ваши примеры (с существительным) вряд ли подпадают под подобные условия. Поэтому логичнее считать, что в них суффикс отсутствующий, а не нулевой.

Ну и википедию еще до кучи. Суть там правильно изложена.
Нулевой аффикс - это ***значимое*** отсутствие, а не просто отсутствие.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, кажется, мое представление о нулевом суффиксе  значительно прояснилось, особенно в части парадигм. Если все суффиксы делятся на формообразующие и словообразующие, то это, наверное,  касается и нулевого суффикса. У формообразующих суффиксов (суффикса Л) парадигма проявляется при сравнении различных форм слова (ожёг – ожгла – ожгло, здесь суффикс Л противопоставлен нулевому суффиксу), а у словообразующих суффиксов парадигму составляют разные суффиксы с одним значением: бегать – бег – беготня (действие и название действия, суффикс -отн- противопоставлен нулевому суффиксу.

Comment: Тогда получается: ожечь – ожёг  (нулевой формообразующий суффикс), бегать – бег, ожечь – ожог (нулевой словообразующий суффикс). Было бы странно считать, что в  глаголе и существительном одинаковая основа (бегу – бегом), основы родственных слов должны отличаться на суффикс, в том числе нулевой. Также хочется сказать о терминологии: как мне кажется, не стоит пользоваться термином «бессуффиксный способ образования слов», а лучше говорить о нулевой аффиксации, смешение этих терминов и приводит к различному толкованию темы, отсутствие суффикса и нулевой суффикс  - это совсем не одно и то же.

Comment: Sergey, Вы сейчас последним комментарием влезаете в академические дебри, вряд ли это тема для данного ресурса. Просто здесь нет человека, который досконально ориентируется во всех тонкостях спора школ и терминологий. По мне так школьное представление о *"бессуфиксальном"* (опять-таки терминология!) образовании представляется объединяющим в себе два случая, разделяемых академической наукой: отсутствие  суффикса как такового и собственно нулевой суффикс. Поэтому Ваша идея о замене одного термина другим не выглядит корректной. Может я и ошибаюсь, хорошо бы Людмила прокомметнировала, если сможет.

Comment: *Тогда получается: ожечь – ожёг (нулевой формообразующий суффикс), * - а шут его знает, если честно. Как посмотреть, Почему Вы настаиваете на одинаковой основе? Ведь древнее, якобы корневое, чередование Г/Ч проявилось здесь не само по себе а под дейстивием чередование позиционного - Ч здест ревлекс сочетания корня жег и мягкого Т в суффиксе Ти: "ожегти". Так что в ожечь основу можно выделять по-разному, с учетом того, что "Ч" - это сращение суффикса и части корня и по современному, с учетом представления о морфемном переразложении (по школьному - чередовании).

Comment: О выбора платформы  зависит и решение вопроса о выделении основы в "ожечь", а следовательно и о том, одинаковая ли основа в ожечь и ожег.  Ну и опосредовано - о наличии/отсутствии нулевого  аффикса.  С этими древними словами, поменявшими свой облик, вечные недоразумения. Не нашего уровня этот вопрос.

Comment: Да, наверное, Вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Действительно, в примерах  ходить – ход (1), ожечь – ожог наблюдается нулевой словообразовательный суффикс. Эти существительные являются производными, т. е. они образованы от глаголов *ходить, ожечь* с помощью суффикса, который формально не представлен. Этот суффикс называют нулевым. См.: 
[Нулевой словообразующий суффикс](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#8)

Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников

Comment: **Galina Avanesova**, Вы были неправы в замене "ожечь – ожог" на "ожечь – ожёг"! В "ожёг" (форме глагола "ожечь") -- **не нулевой словообразовательный, а нулевой  формообразовательный суффикс!**

Comment: Серж, Вы опять ошиблись. Не надо путать нулевой суффикс с  отсутствием суффикса.

Comment: @slava1947. *В "ожёг" (форме глагола "ожечь")* - нету там нулевого суффикса. Ни *словообразующего*, ни *формообразующего* (именно такие термины используются, не надо их переиначивать).

Comment: Ошибаетесь Вы, как всегда!Вы все знаете лучше всех!! А нельзя взять учебник в руки и почитать, прежде чем ставить минусы?! Кстати, это уже говорите не мне, а Литниевской! Потрудились бы прочитать о словообразовательных суффиксах!

Comment: _behemothus: именно такие термины используются, не надо их переиначивать_ ===


Встретил месяца два назад что-то подобное в комментарии от Галины Аванесовой… Тогда улыбнулся, сейчас недоумеваю: уж Вам-то такие легкомысленные заявления совсем не к лицу! _"Именно такие термины используются…"_ Вопрос: кем используются?  Розенталь и Теленкова говорили и "словообразовательный", и "словообразующий"... Не видят различия в терминах и Литневская (_Некорневые морфемы делятся на словообразующие (словообразовательные) и формообразующие (формообразовательные)…_), и ряд других лингвистов...

Comment: Покажите мне у Розенталя и Теленковой "слооборазовательный" (как синоним словобразующему) - и я извинюсь. А что до Галины, это ваши с ней терки, без меня разберетесь. Надо смотреть контекст, почему она так сказала - и т.д. Не царское это дело. )))

Comment: Серж, можно взять учебник, но если при этом нет желания или разума понять, что именно там написано, то остается только посылать туда других. Литвиневская не умполномачивала вас решать за неё, что она сказала. Наверняка Вы опять переврали, даже смотреть не буду.

Comment: 1) слово должно быть производно, мотивировано другим словом языка (поэтому слово гам не имеет нулевого суффикса),

2) должно иметься словообразовательное значение, которое может выражаться ненулевым суффиксом, но в данном случае оно материально не выражено: бежать ® бег-Æ- , бегать ® бег-отн-я.

Comment: _behemothus: Покажите мне у Розенталя и Теленковой "словообразовательный" (как синоним словообразующему) - и я..._ === Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976: _**Суффикс словообразовательный (словообразующий)**_  См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1637

Comment: ***Литвиневская не умполномачивала вас решать за неё, что она сказала.*** Наверно,она вас уполномочивала.  Впрочем,как и другие лингвисты,что вы за всех решаете.

Comment: @behemothus: _Покажите мне у Розенталя и Теленковой "словообразовательный" (как синоним словообразующему) - **и я извинюсь**_. === Показал. Более трёх лет уже прошло...

Comment: @slava1947 ну за три года я, понятно, забыл, за что мне надо извиняться. Смешение понятий мне и сейчас кажется странным. А это точно Розенталь?!)))) А, да... Ну значит, придется извиняться. Но о чем спор был - правда не помню. Надо перечитывать, а сил сейчас нет.